# MVC Sitemap two pages should link the same node

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I use a MvcSitemap for main menu and I need to organize that two actions refer one node in menu. For example page Product and there is a filtering on the page.

> controller="Product" action="Index" 
>   controller="Product" action="Filter"

Now I have this node defined:

> < mvcSiteMapNode title="Product" controller="Product" action="Index"/>

It works correct. The right menu item is selected. But when "Filter" action works, none of menu items is defined.
Is it possible when filtering is done, "Product" node in menu is selected?

Answer (score 0):

The SiteMap requires that each node must have a unique URL, otherwise it won't be able to differentiate between them when looking up the "current" node. In that case, the first match will always win.

You can work around this limitation by adding an additional query string parameter to the URL.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Filtered Product" controller="Product" action="Filter" filtered="true"/>
```

Or by making the request unique by changing the route configuration to include an extra route parameter.

If the URLs are both Internet facing, you can tell search engines that you meant to put the same content on 2 URLs by using the canonicalKey attribute.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Product" controller="Product" action="Index" key="Product_Index"/>
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Filtered Product" controller="Product" action="Filter" filtered="true" canonicalKey="Product_Index"/>
```

And then add the canonical HTML helper to the head section of your layout page.

```
<head>
    @Html.MvcSiteMap().CanonicalTag()
</head>
```

**References**

http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/10/mvcsitemapprovider-4-seo-features#canonical-tag
https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Multiple-Navigation-Paths-to-a-Single-Page
https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/HtmlHelper-extensions